# Closed as duplicate by single user?

Tags: bug, vote-to-close

I'm confused. I saw a question closed as duplicate by someone with substantial reputation ([JavaScript Hoisting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23631758/javascript-hoisting/23631802)). He isn't a moderator.

I thought all votes to close required a majority of 5 votes.

Comment: You can if you have a gold badge for the tag

Comment: @asawyer i just see the new event.

Comment: They have earned superpowers, we all have. Well if you have a gold badge you did.